# Execute several method in text on one object

Tags: php

These are my example class:

```
class First {
   public function getSecond();
}

class Second {
   public function getThird();
}

class Third {}
```

If I want to execute one method from text I can:

```
$first = new First();

$method = 'getSecond';

$first->$method();
```

This is working good, but I would like to run several methods on my object.

Unfortunately I have these method in array:

```
$first = new First();

$methods = array('getSecond', 'getThird');
```

So how can I make something like that:

```
$first = new First();

$methodsInOneLine = implode('()', $methods);

$first->$methods;
```

But of course this isn't working...

Comment: Are you sure you need this? For me this smells like a bad design, but I can not know what you are trying to achieve. In most cases, accessing a method by a string is not the right way! I guess you are trying to implement the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate that array within for loop and need to access elements one by one like below.

```
$methods = array('getSecond', 'getThird');
$first = new First();

for($i=0;$i<count($methods);i++){

    $methodsInOneLine = $methods[$i];
    $first->$methodsInOneLine;    
}
```